# float: left on element inside a horizontally scrolling container breaks layout

Tags: html, css, layout

My container, with the horizontally scrolling elements, go like this:

```
<header id="id-grid-top-menu">

  <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper">
    <a class="cd-dropdown-trigger">CPB1</a> 
    <nav class="cd-dropdown" style="top: 55px; left: 30px;">
        ...nav code here...
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper">
    <a class="cd-dropdown-trigger">CPB1</a> 
    <nav class="cd-dropdown" style="top: 55px; left: 30px;">
        ...nav code here...
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper">
    <a class="cd-dropdown-trigger">CPB1</a> 
    <nav class="cd-dropdown" style="top: 55px; left: 30px;">
        ...nav code here...
    </nav>
  </div>
  .......more divs.....
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#id-grid-top-menu {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 10% !important;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
}

.cd-dropdown-wrapper {
    float: none;
    height: initial !important;
    position: static !important;
    margin: 15px 15px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Right now, this looks like this:

[image]

(sorry, ignore the CPB2)

This has the `.cd-dropdown-wrapper`s line up horizontally and the container lets it overflow with `overflow-x: scroll`. However, I am forced to set `float: none` on the `.cd-dropdown-wrapper` element. If I have less divs, it looks like this:

[image]

The elements are all centered. This, obviously, doesn't look good and I want the elements to line up on the left. However, if I set `float: left` on the elements, they don't line up anymore and overflow; they just wrap around.

[image]

```
.cd-dropdown-wrapper {
    float: left;
}
```

How would I make it so it'll line up on the left but still it will overflow if it extends screen width?

**EDIT:**

I found something interesting. If, in `#id-grid-top-menu`, I set a fixed width--say, 100em. If I apply `float: left` to the `.cd-dropdown-wrapper`, it lines up on the left, and it overflows! However the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding onto @Fabio 's code, I put `float: left` on `#floatcontainer` and `float: none` on the `cd-dropdown-wrapper`'s. That made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another container with fixed width inside header tag.

```
<header id="id-grid-top-menu">
  <div id="floatcontainer">
    <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper">
      <a class="cd-dropdown-trigger">CPB1</a>
      <nav class="cd-dropdown" style="top: 55px; left: 30px;">
        ...nav code here...
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper">
      <a class="cd-dropdown-trigger">CPB1</a>
      <nav class="cd-dropdown" style="top: 55px; left: 30px;">
        ...nav code here...
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper">
      <a class="cd-dropdown-trigger">CPB1</a>
      <nav class="cd-dropdown" style="top: 55px; left: 30px;">
        ...nav code here...
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#floatcontainer {
   width: 3000px;
}
```

Comment: @MingleLi you can't set fixed width to header because of float elements inside... you always need another container with fixed width to make scrollbar appear

Comment: This does not work unfortunately. This causes the scroll bar to be able to scroll way past the divs.

Comment: It's strange. It works sometimes, but then when I open the dropdown it magically doesn't work; the scrollbar, as I said, shrinks so it scrolls way too far.

Comment: Your answer (well, the only answer) has been the most helpful so far. I'll upvote it but I won't accept because there's still something wrong. I'm guessing it's a problem on my end, I'll try to fix it if so.

Comment: @MingleLi try to add width: 100% (or a fixed max-width) to header tag

Comment: Nope, no change

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't help you to make it works perfectly, I should see the full code to understand where is the problem.